# Embedding youtube videos from others on my website

Tags: youtube

Almost all (if not all) videos on YouTube have the "Embed" link below them. Can I always embed other people's videos on my website (stating source and author)? I simply want to include some videos related to my website's topic and was wondering if I can embed Youtube videos in a "Video" section on our website.

I have noted many videos have a "Standard YouTube License", but this is not linked to anything and I'm not sure what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can embed videos.
When someone doesn't want their video to be embeddable, after starting playing video on your site the user would see the message that says something like "this video can't be embeded, go to youtube.com [link to video] " to view it.

Comment: OK so no legal issues embedding these videos?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Uploading video to Youtube you allow everyone to embed public videos on their site. Except when you disable it, and then user is asked to view video directly on Youtube.